# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager` while attempting to activate 'xxxxx.LoginModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have scaffolded the Identity using the CLI as

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Then I list all the files

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --listFiles
```

I used the login `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --files="Account.Login"`
Now I can see in the Area section the login.cshtml file is generated

[image]

Now when I navigate to `https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DVotingApplication%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5001%252Fauthentication%252Flogin-callback%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3DVotingApplicationAPI%2520openid%2520profile%26state%3Daceb10c45488493b9a675c830327ecbf%26code_challenge%3DnU-0BBK2wjgOSEDdB4Qjy5T8f3qHWTlgu0UmMgVDEAU%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26response_mode%3Dquery`

I get an exception as

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'VotingApplication.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.
```

In the startup.cs I have the below configuration

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Since I am using the `ApplicationUser`, I am not able to see the account controller when I do the scaffolder.

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        });
    }
}
```

Since the scaffolder is using `IdentityUser`, how can I make this to work with `ApplicationUser`

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using global::Data
@using global::Data.Domain
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@{
    string returnUrl = null;
    var query = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
    if (query.ContainsKey("returnUrl"))
    {
        returnUrl = query["returnUrl"];
    }
}

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="/">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks you inject `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` into your `Login.cshtml.cs` file, but that should be `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` according to the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'VotingApplication.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

It seems that you [update the `IdentityUser` derived class with custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-user-data) and name it as `ApplicationUser`.

And based on your description and code, we can find that you just replaced `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` in `ConfigureServices` method and `_LoginPartial.cshtml` file, you seems not update `Login.cshtml.cs` file to replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`, which cause the issue.

Please make sure you inject the instance of **UserManager** and **SignInManager** within `LoginModel` class using `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>`, like below.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a class that dependents on ApplicationSignInManager. You need to register ApplicationSignInManager

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
        {
            // identityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
            // identityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()      // <- use only if use have custom implementation
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>(); // <- use only if use have custom implementation
```

you can find sample implementation [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/c281dfcf6a9307ad1c0d3dd18562c4beabd8c46c/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Startup.cs#L36)

Comment: what are ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationSignInManager, I don't have any implementation of those manager

Comment: @SanJaisy, you can comment these two lines. The default implementation will be selected.